# Not Sync Azure database into Local Sqlite database in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, azure-mobile-services

I used Azure database into Sqlite database Coding..ToDoItem table correctly Work in sync code..But, I create New table with UUID field.But, My table not sync local database.Please Help me.Follow my code..

```
  private AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> initLocalStore() throws MobileServiceLocalStoreException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {

                MobileServiceSyncContext syncContext = mClient.getSyncContext();


                if (syncContext.isInitialized())
                    return null;

                SQLiteLocalStore localStore = new SQLiteLocalStore(mClient.getContext(), "OfflineStore111", null, 1);

                Map<String, ColumnDataType> tableDefinition = new HashMap<String, ColumnDataType>();
                tableDefinition.put("Id", ColumnDataType.String); // Id Datatype Custom(UUId).How I set ColumnDataType???
                tableDefinition.put("BranchCode", ColumnDataType.String);
                tableDefinition.put("BranchName", ColumnDataType.String);
                tableDefinition.put("Description", ColumnDataType.String);
                tableDefinition.put("SortCode", ColumnDataType.String);
                tableDefinition.put("Enable", ColumnDataType.Boolean);
                tableDefinition.put("BusinessUnitId", ColumnDataType.String); //  Datatype Custom(UUId)..How I set ColumnDataType???
                tableDefinition.put("CreatedUserId", ColumnDataType.String);
                tableDefinition.put("ModifiedUserId", ColumnDataType.String);
                tableDefinition.put("CreatedDate", ColumnDataType.String); // Datatype Custom(Date)..How I set ColumnDataType???
                tableDefinition.put("ModifiedDate", ColumnDataType.String); // Datatype Custom(Date)..How I set ColumnDataType???

                localStore.defineTable("Branches", tableDefinition);

                SimpleSyncHandler handler = new SimpleSyncHandler();

                syncContext.initialize(localStore, handler).get();



            } catch (final Exception e) {
                createAndShowDialogFromTask(e, "Error");

            }

            return null;
        }
    };

    return runAsyncTask(task);
}
```

Comment: Whats the error / exception?

Comment: sync not initialized error